# Full Calendar - Check if there is an event in the same day

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js, fullcalendar

I've users that need to save their availability. I'm using Full Calendar and I need to check if they have an event already when they click some day (If they are available one they, don't need to put it more than once). I'm using VueJs and I have all the events in the store. So I try this:

```
handleSelect(arg) {
   let index = this.$store.getters.EVENTS.findIndex((_event) => _event.start == arg.start);
   if (index == -1) {
     this.$store.dispatch("ADD_EVENT", {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        title: this.title,
        start: arg.start,
        end: arg.end,
        allDay: arg.allDay,
     });
   }
},
```

If I console.log _event.start and arg.start, both are the same but I'm getting index -1 always. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
event.start is an object so I need to getTime to compare dates. So my new code is like this:

```
handleSelect(arg) {
  let index = this.$store.getters.EVENTS.find(
    _event =>
      _event.start.getTime() == arg.start.getTime() &&
      _event.end.getTime() == arg.end.getTime()
  );

  if (!index) {
    this.$store.dispatch("ADD_EVENT", {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      title: this.title,
      start: arg.start,
      end: arg.end,
      allDay: arg.allDay
    });
  }
},
```